# Entity Framework mapping two table columns to same related table Key

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, composite-primary-key, ef-database-first, entity-framework-designer

I'm in a situation where I have a table called `Elements`. Now I'm creating a table called `Divergences` that will store basically pairs of `Elements`. The purpose of `Divergence` is to check if two `Elements` have diverging answers.

```
Element               Divergence
---------             ----------
ElementId             ElementId1
                      ElementId2
```

In the above table schema, `ElementId1` and `ElementId2` are *Foreign Keys* mapping to `ElementId` in `Elements` table and form the *composite primary key* for the `Divergence` table.

I use *Database First approach* where I create the tables in SQL Server Management Studio and later I do a `Update Model from Database...` in Entity Framework Designer.

The problem I'm facing is that when EF Designer generates the model it creates 2 sets `ICollection<Element>` inside the `Element` class namely `Elements` and `Elements1`.

[image]

This doesn't give me a `Divergences` DbSet.

What I'd want to have is a `Divergence` class where I'd do something like this in code:

```
Divergence d = new Divergence();
d.Element1 = element1;
d.Element2 = element2;

Database.Divergences.Add(d);
Database.SaveChanges();
```

and later on:

```
Element e = Database.Elements.Single(e => e.ElementId == 7);

var divergences = e.Divergences;
```

I tried adding a new column to the `Divergence` table like this:

```
Element               Divergence
---------             ------------
ElementId             DivergenceId
                      ElementId1
                      ElementId2
```

This correctly leads to a `1 <-> *` relationship in Entity Framework Designer. I finally get a `Divergences` DbSet but `DivergenceId` property is useless in the code and I still get the 2 sets in the `Element` class. It's important to note that `ElementId1` and `ElementId2` still form the composite primary key.

What do you think is the correct way of mapping this specific situation? Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of...

```
Divergence d = new Divergence();
d.Element1 = element1;
d.Element2 = element2;

Database.Divergences.Add(d);
Database.SaveChanges();
```

... you could actually use:

```
element1.Elements = new List<Element>();
// if that collection isn't already instantiated, for example in the constructor
element1.Elements.Add(element2);

Database.SaveChanges();
```

This will create exactly the same SQL `INSERT` statements to the link table without the need of having a `Divergence` entity. (Change tracking will recognize that you changed the relationship by adding an item to the collection and infer the necessary SQL commands from this change. `element1` and `element2` must be attached to the context in state `Unchanged`, but that is also required for your original code in order to work correctly.)

Also, instead of ...

```
Element e = Database.Elements.Single(e => e.ElementId == 7);
var divergences = e.Divergences;
```

... you can fetch the columns from the `Divergences` table like so:

```
var divergences = Database.Elements.Where(e => e.ElementId == 7)
    .SelectMany(e1 => e1.Elements.Select(e2 => new
    {
        ElementId1 = e1.ElementId,
        ElementId2 = e2.ElementId,
    }))
    .ToList();
```

So, you will get your desired results without the `Divergence` entity and honestly I would use it this way. I'm not aware of a way to force EF to create that entity with database first approach, unless you introduce some artificial additional column like you did. If there is a way it is probably a hack or more difficult to achieve and maintain than just working with EF's default, that is without a `Divergence` entity.

However, you could consider to remove one of the collections (just delete it in the model surface). Having both is a bit confusing in this model in my opinion. Or at least rename them to `SourceElements` and `TargetElements` for example :)

Comment: Awesome Slauma! That's it... I'm going to implement it this way since as you said there's no built in functionality to map the way I wanted. Thank you very much for your attention! :)