# Many-to-many relationship between the same class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to implement what seems like a pretty common case - a Friendship relationship between 2 users. I think the models are self-explanatory. `Friendship` needs to have 2 users on it and also some data about the relationship, and users have a `Friendships` property, which is populated by any friendship they are a part of, as either `User1` or `User2`. I couldn't figure out a nicer way to name the 2 users. Here are my models:

```
public class Friendship : Entity
{
    public ApplicationUser User1 { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User2 { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual List<Friendship> Friendships { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Here's my attempt at configuring the relationship in `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Friendships)
    .WithRequired()
    .Map(t => t.MapKey("User1_Id", "User2_Id"));
```

I don't think I'm doing the configuration right. Here's the error I'm getting when trying to create a migration from this:

`The specified association foreign key columns 'User1_Id, User2_Id' are invalid. The number of columns specified must match the number of primary key columns.`

Is it possible to accomplish this using ef6? A special thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: Without testing it, I would think that the "WithRequired(...)" would not work, since it is not satisfied when not associating two users to each other. In your case it's one-way: only one is the friend of the other, the other one is only "befriended" (not sure if that words exists).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean the addition of this line `requestedUser.IncomingFriendRequests.Add(friendRequest);`? I had that in there before and took it out, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: The many to many relationships I am used to do not use the "WithRequired()", instead it uses a direct declaration of a mapping table without the "WithRequired()": Sample (this will look funny in a comment block): modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(x => x.IncomingFriendRequests)
                .WithMany(x => x. OutgoingFriendRequests)
                .Map(x =>
                {
                    x.ToTable("FriendRequest");
                    x.MapLeftKey("RequestingUserId");
                    x.MapRightKey("RequestedUserId");
                });

Comment: Possible duplicate [EntityFramework Same Table Many to Many Relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12331031/580951).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Romoku, but this doesn't quite solve my problem. This implementation says I can't add any other columns to the relationship table, as there is no intermediary class to represent the relationship. It's very close, but I do need other pieces of information about the relationship beyond simply who the 2 users are that are friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into a [multiplicity constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20034003/580951). The `Friendship` class has two users which creates a cycle from `ApplicationUser` -> `Friendship` -> `ApplicationUser`. To fix this remove the `User1` and `User2` property and add a collection `ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users`.

DTO:

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext()
        : base("ApplicationContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Relationship> Relationships { get; set; }
}

public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class User : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Relationship> Relationships { get; set; }
}

public class Relationship : Entity
{
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Sample:

```
var bob = new User
{
    Name = "Bob",
    Relationships = new List<Relationship>()
};

var fred = new User
{
    Name = "Fred",
    Relationships = new List<Relationship>()
};

var relationship = new Relationship
{
    Users = new List<User>
    {
        bob,
        fred
    }
};

bob.Relationships.Add(relationship);
fred.Relationships.Add(relationship);

using(var context = new ApplicationContext())
{
    context.Users.Add(bob);
    context.Users.Add(fred);
    context.Relationships.Add(relationship);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```